# Painfully slow query, what are my options?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, database-design, query-optimization

I do some sql work at a hospital (no COVID cases yet!). There is a table, `[dbo].A.diagnosis`, that contains a historical record of all diagnoses all of our patients have had. I'm no expert, but the table is... bad. It's used by this ancient piece of software that we use here to handle diagnoses (among other things). The way the table works, it has 30+ columns and 300k+ rows, but no index (except on its primary key). Each time a patient gets their diagnosis updated, all their diagnoses are re-written to the table under the new `diagnosis_date`. `diagnosis_date` is stored at datatype `date` instead of `datetime`, but it's not uncommon for a patient to have a diagnosis updated multiple times in a day.

I need to get a list of all our currently-admitted patients, and have it be reasonably up to date (I'd say within the last 24 hours is reasonable, but sooner is preferred).

My current best query is still highly variable in run time, taking anywhere from 1 to 15(!!!) minutes to run. That's not acceptable, so I want to know what my options are to improve it.

Sample of data (fictional, only the relevant columns):

```
-- [dbo].A.diagnosis
+------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| patient_id | diagnosis_type | diagnosis_date | diagnosis_code | diagnosis_text              |
+------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| 0369344991 | I              | 2020-01-04     | E669           | Obesity, unspecified        |
| 0369344991 | I              | 2020-01-04     | M545           | Low back pain               |
| 0369344991 | I              | 2020-01-04     | NULL           | NULL                        | -- Separator
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-04     | E669           | Obesity, unspecified        |
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-04     | M545           | Low back pain               |
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-04     | L709           | Acne, unspecified           | -- Updated later that day to add the acne diagnosis
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-04     | NULL           | NULL                        |
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-16     | E669           | Obesity, unspecified        |
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-16     | L709           | Acne, unspecified           |
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-16     | E785           | Hyperlipidemia, unspecified | -- Updated 12 days later, low back pain resolved, added hyperlipidemia
| 0369344991 | U              | 2020-01-16     | NULL           | NULL                        |
+------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+

-- [dbo].A.patients
+------------+
| patient_id |
+------------+
| 0369344991 |
+------------+

-- [dbo].B.diagnosis_priority
+----------------+--------------------+
| diagnosis_type | diagnosis_priority |
+----------------+--------------------+
| I              | 1                  |
| A              | 2                  |
| U              | 3                  |
| D              | 4                  |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dx.patient_id -- (decimal(10,0), null)
,       dx.diagnosis_date -- (date, null)
,       dx.diagnosis_code -- (varchar(5), null)
,       dx.diagnosis_text -- (varchar(253, null) 
,       dx.diagnosis_type -- (varchar(1), null)
FROM    [dbo].A.patients -- Starting with a list of our current patients.
JOIN    [dbo].A.diagnosis dx
    ON  [dbo].A.patients.patient_id = dx.patient_id
JOIN    [dbo].B.diagnosis_priority dp 
    ON  dx.diagnosis_type = dp.diagnosis_type
-- This is a table I wrote to help determine which diagnoses are more 'up-to-date' if multiple updates are done on 
-- a single day. The join assigns a priority number to each diagnosis_type as diagnosis_priority.
WHERE   dx.diagnosis_code IS NOT NULL
AND     dx.diagnosis_date = ( -- Trying to get the diagnoses as of the most recent diagnosis date.
            SELECT  MAX(dx_a.diagnosis_date) 
            FROM    [dbo].A.diagnosis dx_a 
            WHERE   dx_a.patient_id = dx.patient_id
            ) 
AND     dp.diagnosis_priority = (  
-- Trying to get the highest priority diagnoses applied on the most recent date.
-- A patient will not get a lower priority diagnosis on a later date, but newer diagnoses will not 
-- necessarily get a higher priority in [dbo].A.diagnosis
            SELECT  MAX(dp_a.diagnosis_priority) 
            FROM    [dbo].A.diagnosis dx_a 
            JOIN    [dbo].B.diagnosis_priority dp_a 
                ON dx_a.diagnosis_type = dp_a.diagnosis_type 
            WHERE dx_a.patient_id = dx.patient_id
            )
```

I'm a member of `db_datareader` on `[dbo].A`, but I'm a member of `db_owner` on `[dbo].B` on the same server. Modifying the way `[dbo].A.diagnosis` functions is not feasible because of the aforementioned ancient piece of software.

If the query can't be improved significantly, I want to know what options I have on `[dbo].B` to maintain a list of current diagnoses for patients currently at the hospital.

Comment: The sample data you have provided here is only of one table, you have 5 table references in the above. The `DISTINCT` and only referencing columns for `dx` even though you have 3 tables in the `FROM` and another 2 in a sub-query in the `WHERE` has a "code smell" to it. Posting the query plan (use Paste the Plan) and DDL of the objects (including indexes) might well help us help you, however, I suspect that what you may actually need is an `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` and possibly not even that subquery if you use a CTE and a windowed function.

Comment: `SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'A'`

Comment: Then I would suggest talking to one of your DBAs for help. Without a query plan, DDL and indexes, we have an impossible task ahead of us. We could, possibly, rewrite the query but we'd still sample data and expected results and a description of the logic involved.

Comment: Talking to a DBA isn't possible, for reasons I can't really get into. An impossible task is what I have.

Comment: Then talk to someone internally that has knowledge of the database schema and indexes, etc.

Comment: Few tips to start - move inner queries to CTEs, since now they are running for each row. Next - limit the result set to get it as less as possible - then you can extract a temp table with required data and create indexes on it.  If you can provide more info it will be useful,

Comment: `JOIN [dbo].B.diagnosis_priority dp ON  dx.diagnosis_type = dp.diagnosis_type` seems wrong. Shouldn't it be `JOIN [dbo].B.diagnosis_priority dp ON  dx.patient_id = dp.patient_id and dx.diagnosis_type = dp.diagnosis_type`?

Comment: 1. What version of SQL Server are you running on? 2. What DB compatibility settings are used? 3.You are hitting `diagnosis ` table (your largest) 3 times, never going to be fast. It may also slow down legacy app as well, as you would be holding a  lot of locks on this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream all of the data out to a temp table and run your query on the temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #diagnosis_tmp (patient_id decimal(10,0), diagnosis_type varchar(1), diagnosis_date date, diagnosis_code varchar(5), diagnosis_text varchar(253))

INSERT INTO #diagnosis_tmp (patient_id,diagnosis_type,diagnosis_date,diagnosis_code)
SELECT patient_id,diagnosis_type,diagnosis_date,diagnosis_code
FROM [dbo].A.diagnosis
    WHERE diagnosis_code IS NOT NULL

--CREATE INDEX i_patient_date ON #diagnosis_tmp (patient_id,diagnosis_date)
```